# Compute this limit ? Dominated convergence is not applicable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let $\theta_{i}\in \mathbb{R}$, $i=1,2$ and let $m$ be a positive integer.

Compute the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ of

$${\epsilon}^{-1}\int_{2\epsilon}^{1} x^{m+1}\left(\frac{1}{(x+\epsilon e^{\imath \theta_{1}})^{m+1}}-\frac{1}{(x+\epsilon e^{\imath \theta_{2}})^{m+1}} \right)dx\\
=(e^{\imath \theta_{2}}-e^{\imath \theta_{1}})
\int_{0}^{1} x^{m+1}\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{m}
(x+\epsilon e^{\imath \theta_{1}})^{j}
(x+\epsilon e^{\imath \theta_{2}})^{m-j}
}{(x+\epsilon e^{\imath \theta_{1}})^{m+1}(x+\epsilon e^{\imath \theta_{2}})^{m+1}}\,\chi_{[2\epsilon,1]}(x)\, dx.$$

Notice that the integrand in the latter integral converges to  ${(m+1)}/{x}$ when $\epsilon \to 0$. So dominated convergence is not applicable here.

Of course the integral is asymptotically equivalent to $C\log{\epsilon}$ with some number $C$. How show that rigorously ?

Comment: Since the integral can be computed explicitly, we can perform a pretty detailed analysis on the asymptotic behavior of the integral. If I computed correctly, it is $$ (e^{i\theta_1} - e^{i\theta_2})(m+1)\log\epsilon + \mathcal{O}(1)$$ as $\epsilon\to 0^+$. I would like to write down my computation, but I'm typing this with my tablet now and it's real pain to typeset formulas with it...

Comment: Please, give a hint on how to compute the integral explicitly. By, the look of it, you expanded the rational factor about $\epsilon=0$, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $n = m+1$ for simplicity. Then for $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|\alpha| < \min\{2\epsilon, 1\}$,

\begin{align*}
\int_{2\epsilon}^{1} \frac{x^n}{(x+\alpha)^n} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{2\epsilon}^{1} \frac{((x + \alpha) - \alpha)^n}{(x+\alpha)^n} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (-\alpha)^k \int_{2\epsilon}^{1} \frac{1}{(x+\alpha)^k} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= (1 - 2\epsilon) - n\alpha(\log(1+\alpha) - \log(2\epsilon+\alpha)) \\
&\quad  + \sum_{k=2}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{(-\alpha)^k}{k-1} \left( \frac{1}{(2\epsilon+\alpha)^{k-1}} - \frac{1}{(1+\alpha)^{k-1}} \right).
\end{align*}

Substituting $\alpha = \epsilon \beta$ with $|\beta| < 2$ and dividing both sides by $\epsilon$,

\begin{align*}
\epsilon^{-1}\int_{2\epsilon}^{1} \frac{x^n}{(x+\epsilon\alpha)^n} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \epsilon^{-1} + n\beta\log\epsilon - 2 + n\beta(\log(2+\beta) - \log(1+\epsilon\beta)) \\
&\quad  + \sum_{k=2}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{(-\beta)^k}{k-1} \left( \frac{1}{(2+\beta)^{k-1}} - \frac{\epsilon^{k-1}}{(1+\epsilon\beta)^{k-1}} \right) \\
&= \epsilon^{-1} + n\beta\log\epsilon + \mathcal{O}_{\beta}(1)
\end{align*}

as $\epsilon \to 0^+$. This is enough to conclude that OP's integral is

$$ n(e^{i\theta_1} - e^{i\theta_2})\log\epsilon + \mathcal{O}(1).$$